Why this code gives me compiler error: "Static assertion failed due to...the hash does not meet the Hash requirement"
Code pasted below:
auto myComp = []( std::array<const string, 3> &a, std::array<const string, 3> &b )
{
    if ( a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1] && a[2] == b[2] ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
auto myHash = []( std::array<const string, 3> &a )
{
    return std::hash<std::string>()( a[0] )
    ^ std::hash<std::string>()( a[1] )
    ^ std::hash<std::string>()( a[2] );
};
std::unordered_set<std::array<const string, 3>, decltype( myHash ), decltype( myComp )> unordSet( 16, myHash, myComp );

The whole error message is:
MacOSX15.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__hash_table:607:17 Static assertion failed due to requirement 'integral_constant<bool, false>::value': the specified hash does not meet the Hash requirements

Many thanks in advance.
EDIT:
I managed to find out the definition of the check:
#ifndef _LIBCPP_CXX03_LANG
template <class _Key, class _Hash>
using __check_hash_requirements _LIBCPP_NODEBUG =
    integral_constant<bool,
                      is_copy_constructible<_Hash>::value && is_move_constructible<_Hash>::value &&
                          __invokable_r<size_t, _Hash, _Key const&>::value >;

Turns out it is this condition that fails the test:
__invokable_r<size_t, _Hash, _Key const&>::value


FWIW - gcc does accept the code, but not MSVC nor clang (see demo).

I am not sure it is relevant, but one of the requirements for std::hash is that the elements are CopyAssignable, which is not valid here because of the const std::string.

Hi @wohlstad, your replies are greatly appreciate. I also cannot reproduce it on my Linux server GCC12.3. For const std::string, I am afraid it is not the cause, a plain string cannot pass too.

Aside: if (cond) return true; else return false; can — and should — always be replaced by return cond;. Don’t write unnecessary boilerplate code.

First argument to _Hash must accept _Key const& according to this constraint, your hash function doesn't allow const reference. Change argument to const std::array<const string, 3> &a. Not sure if the standard actually requires that or it's just the compiler invention.

@KonradRudolph, thanks for pointing that out, trying to improve my coding style.

@Yksisarvinen, thanks mate, I changed as you said now it compiles. However it seems not to relate to __invokable_r which fails the static_check, did I miss something?

Also could you kindly teach from where you make the correct claim that "first argument to _Hash must accept _Key const& according to this constraint", I'd appreciate it a lot if you could elaborate and make it an answer.

@PkDrew This __invokable_r says that _Hash should be invocable with only one argument being _Key const& and it should return size_t. Your function did not allow const ref argument, because it required non-const ref.

@KonradRudolph • unless you are a contractor being paid by the KLOC.

@Yksisarvinen, cheers mate, fully clear now, awkward I somehow cannot find the definition of __invokable_r even by grep, but seeing its naming and your answer, I assume it means when _Hash is called, its arg must include _Key const&? also I am confused why the const& is placed after _Key, shouldn't it be before _Key?

@PkDrew __invokable_r is some compiler/standard library internal implementation. Better to look up how standard defines std::is_invocable_r. About the other things: & must be placed after type. const can be placed before or after, and west const vs. east const is a longstanding debate, people just choose one of preference.

@Yksisarvinen, hats off.

Use const std::array<T, N>, instead of std::array<const T, N>. If the later compiles, it's a defect in std or the platform.

Yes, you are right, the problem here is that unordered map accepts hashing function only with const reference key, it is necessary in order to guarantee data immutability during different actions to make the container work correctly, it is also accepted in STL library. That is
auto myComp = [](const array<const string, 3> &a, const.   array<const string, 3> &b)
{
    return (a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1] && a[2] == b[2]);
};

auto myHash = [](const array<const string, 3> &a)
{
    return hash<string>()(a[0]) ^ hash<string>()(a[1]) ^ hash<string>()(a[2]);
};

I also suggest you read the book "Effective C++" by Scott Meyers (Chapter 3), which discusses the topic of effective use of const reference

Thanks for answering. But is the regulation anywhere mentioned formally? It seems to be a compiler independent feature, any particular reason why const reference is asked?

Here are the main reasons why const is mandatory in this case:

std::hash and std::unordered_set assume that objects will not change, which is guaranteed by the use of const.
If the data could change, it could compromise the integrity of the data structure.
The use of const meets the requirements of the standard library API.

In the end, the main reason is for the security and immutability of the data for the data structure to work correctly.

This rule is not mandatory at the C++ language level, but it is formally enshrined in the C++ standard library requirements for the correct functioning of containers such as std::unordered_set.

Yeah makes sense, the same way Python asks for, thanks for the explanation mate.
